# Enable submit button if form submission failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've got the following code to disable the submit button after the form has been submitted to prevent multiple submissions at once.

The problem is that if the next page never loads or something happens with the user connection, the button stays disabled.

Is there a way to check if the user is still connected and enabled the button again if submission failed, so that the user can retry to submit the form?

This is my jQuery code:

```
$form.on("submit", function() {
    var emptyInputs = 0;

    // calculate empty inputs

    if (emptyInputs === 0) {
        var $button = $("#signup button");

        $button.prop("disabled", true);

        //if (/* connection is lost / offline */) {
        //    $button.prop("disabled", false);
        //}

        return true;
    }

   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
//callback handler for form submit
$form.submit(function(e)
{        
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            //go to success page
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            // handle fail event your way 
            $("#signup button").removeAttr("disabled");     
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the submit button fires a full page request there isn't a lot you can do as there is no event to trigger the reset. If you were submitting the form as an ajax request you could abort the request after a certain timeout.